# Azure B2C Custom policy - Want to read system generated exception in custom policy

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, azure-ad-b2c

When users enter invalid email address and password, I want to log his/her details like email and reason for exception in DB.

In application insights, I see below error message "*A user with the specified credentials could not be found.*"

Is there anyway that I can capture "Message" value and send it to my REST API?

```
"Statebag": {
        "ComplexItems": "_MachineEventQ, REPRM, JL, TCTX, S_CTP, M_EXCP"
      },
      "Exception": {
        "Kind": "Handled",
        "HResult": "80131500",
        "Message": "A user with the specified credential could not be found.",
        "Data": {
          "IsPolicySpecificError": false
        }
      },
      "PredicateResult": "False"
```